# Explicit solution of $XA=BX$

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Consider the equation $$XA=BX,$$
where $X,A,B$ could be matrices or (pseudo) differential operators.

How to represent $X$ using $A,B$, that is 
$$X=f(A,B),$$
where $f$ is a known function.

Comment: Try $X=0$ as a solution.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to Lyapunov equation?